# MonthCalendar doesn't show on form C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, monthcalendar

I wan't to make a Class/function which must be able to show a calender at a given point on a form.
And then return the selected date.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static string ShowCalendar(Point locatieCalender)
    {
        MonthCalendar calender = new MonthCalendar();
        calender.Location = locatieCalender;
        calender.Show();
        calender.Visible = true;

        string date = calender.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(date);
        string dateForTextbox = dateValue.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        calender.Hide();
        return dateForTextbox;

       }
```

The problem is the calender won't show on the form.

I would appreciate some help with this.
Thanks in advance

Ok Now I've changed my function to :

```
 public static string ShowCalendar(Point locatieCalender, Form F1)
    {
        MonthCalendar calender = new MonthCalendar();
        calender.Location = locatieCalender;
        calender.Show();
        calender.Visible = true;
        calender.BringToFront();
        calender.Parent = F1;
        string date = calender.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(date);

        string dateForTextbox = dateValue.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        //calender.Hide();
        return dateForTextbox;

    }
```

And the function call:

```
string dateForTextbox = HelpFunction.ShowCalendar(calenderLocatie, this);
```

Now the calender shows but no string is returned.
I've tried with event but because of the static function that won't work.

Comment: Why are you calling "calendar.Hide()"?

Comment: I want the calander to hide after the date is selected. But because of the static methode it won't work with a "dateselected" event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the form as a control. See this link for help on how to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

For instance:

```
Controls.Add(calendar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `calender.Hide()` in your code. And add it to your form through `Controls.Add` or `Parent` property, like this:

```
   //....
    string dateForTextbox = dateValue.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    calender.Parent = yourForm;
    return dateForTextbox;
   }
```

I think you should declare a variable of `MonthCalendar` somewhere in your `Form` class, use it in your `ShowCalendar` instead of the local variable `calendar`.

Comment: Maybe I should also have mentioned this methode is in a different class then the form I want to show it on.

Comment: @user2726516 OK, just replace `this` with `your form reference`.